# How to access a value in a function for entire model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. Now i have id  in a variable in one method of a model. I want to access the value where i used the variable for entire model(ie, all function of a model).

Controller:::

```
public function user_id()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['name']))
        {
            $name =$this->input->post('name');                                                      //echo "Posted:".$name;
            $this->UserRight_model->get_id($name);      
        }
    }   
}
```

Moldel code:

```
public function get_id($name)   
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select UserPcKey from UserMaster where UserName='".$name."'");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
              $id= $row->UserPcKey;                                                    
              echo $pckey;
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo "choose valid name"; 
    }                                                                                                   
}
```

I tried to use the id value in other function in a same model i got error due to parameter.

Comment: Where do you find `$pckey` which you echo in foreach loop (there is no any reference to `$pckey`)? Copy/paste error you have got.

Comment: If you want to use that `$id` variable in another function in your model you have to pass it. For instance after `$id = $row->UserPcKey` call the function `$this->yourOtherFunction($id)` . Also as Tpojka pointed, your `$pckey` variable is not declared anywhere visible and may be causing an error.